# Is there any advantage of using helium light for calibration of a spectrometer?

Tags: optics, spectroscopy

Presently I'm working on a finding out the band gaps of certain semiconductor materials, using LED. So for that, first I had to calibrate the spectrometer where I observed the spectrum of helium gas using a grating.

What would happen if I used some other gas, say Hydrogen for the calibration? Helium definitely gives sharp bright lines. So, is that it? What if I used some other gas? Would they give continuous spectra,  making it difficult to take readings?

Comment: Helium has six lines nicely spaced across the visible spectrum.

Comment: What is wrong with this community? This is a viable question, for what do people downvote it? Because you don't like spectroscopy, or what?

Comment: Neon works very well in the 585 nm and longer region. Helium and hydrogen as fine as well. Other good choices are mercury (a mercury pen lamp, not a fluorescent lamp) and argon. And, of course, hollow cathode lamps!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want several things from your calibration source:

- sharp lines (so you can find their position accurately)
- multiple lines (to calibrate the entire spectrum)
- no spurious signals

It turns out that most of the other materials that are used for the spectra don't have all these properties. You can see examples of these spectra at [this link](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/atspect.html) and links therein. From there, an example of helium, hydrogen and nitrogen spectra:

Helium:

[image]

Hydrogen:

[image]

Nitrogen:

[image]

It is not hard to see that the nitrogen spectrum would not be very useful for calibration...

Comment: @TheDarkSide yes I think so

Comment: Yes. But if you know there should be two lines and you see one, you can figure out where the apparent center of your one line should be (using an intensity weighted mean of the lines and should be there). So that is still OK for calibration.